# Use shift to select word until next capital letter

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I am programming and from Windows I'm used to use the **"shift" + "alt" + "arrow key right/left"** keys to select a part from a word until the next capital letter starts. But on my Mac this shortcut only selects the whole word. Can this be done somehow on a Mac too?

**For example:**

myVariable    *(is the text to select, cursor is at the beginning (before 'm')).*

*Now using the shortcut "shift" + "alt" + "arrow key right" would select only 'my':*

**my**Variable  *('my' is selected, pressing it again would then select the whole word.)*

This is a shortcut often needed for example when programming using the programming language Java.

Comment: This may be application-specific. Standard Mac toolbox for that key combo would just be 'add next letter to selection'. Opt/shift/arrow would be add next word. I've never know the 'add until next upper-case' structure at all, but maybe someone else would know.

Comment: @grgarside Sorry, yes, you are right! I forgot to mention the "alt" key.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, **but it only works for the IDE (development environment) I am using**, which is the program [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and not system wide.
But that fits my needs.

**Solution:**

Go to **Preferences > Keymap > Search for "move caret to" > Select "*Move Caret to Next Word in Different "Camel Humps" Mode*" > Double Click it and select "*Add keyboard shortcut*" > Enter any shortcut you want.**

You may also set a shortcut for doing the same thing but in the different direction.